# How to create a simple game loop that doesn't need drawing

Tags: java, android

I'm still having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around game loops and where the code actually sits in the program.  To learn the basics, I would like to add a very simple loop to this activity, but I don't know where to place the code.  What I want is that every 10 seconds, the monster attacks the player.  And every time the player attacks the monster, the attack button is disabled for 5 seconds before the player can attack again.  I know there is a lot written about game loops, but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement what I've read in the simple way that I want to use them.  I don't need to update the information on the screen, the background is static as it is a text-based fight.  Also I want to do is have the battle continue until either the player or monster are dead.

I don't need the exact code to be written, more just the framework on setting up the timer and where to place that in the activity code.

Thank you.

```
public class MonstersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        //variables for the UI
        Button buttonAttack
        View layout;

        //Variables for game
        private Player player;
        private Monster monster;    

        //thread variables
        private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //makes activity run in fullscreen
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_monsters);

            //initiate player object from intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Player player = (Player)intent.getSerializableExtra("player");
            this.player = player;

            //create monster
            monster = new Monster(player.getCurrentCity());

            //assign variables to UI objects
            buttonAttack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAttack);
            monsterHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textMonsterHealth);
            playerHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPlayerHealthMonster);

            //setup onclick listeners
            buttonAttack.setOnClickListener(this);

            //initial UI setup
            battleWindow.setEnabled(false);
            battleWindow.setText("You have encountered a " + monster.getName() + ".  Good luck brave Tobias!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonAttack:
                    //Player attack
                    final int playerAttackDamage = GameElements.battleDamage(player.getPlayerStrength());

                    monster.setHealth(monster.getHealth() - playerAttackDamage);
                    player.setDamageDealt(playerAttackDamage);

                    battleWindow.setEnabled(true);
                    buttonAttack.setEnabled(false);

                    if(monster.getHealth() < 1){
                        player = GameElements.playerWon(player);
                        battleWindow.setText(player.getBattleLog());
                        player.setGP(player.getGP() + monster.getRewardGP());
                        monsterHealth.setText(monster.getName() + "'s Health = " + monster.getHealth());
                    }else {
                        player = GameElements.playerAttack(player);
                        battleWindow.setText(player.getBattleLog());
                        monsterHealth.setText(monster.getName() + "'s Health = " + monster.getHealth());
                        battleResult = 0;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }

    }//Activity Ends
```

Comment: Have you looked into multithreading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can use several [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) to achieve this.

Make an instance for your monster and for your player, so you can set different cooldowns. You can do your actions (disabling the button, restarting the timer, calculate new hp, ...) in the `onFinish()` method of the CountDownTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a game loop is something pretty simple: a thread with a while.

```
run(){
    while(running){
      updateGameState();
    }
}
```

From this you should be able to save elapsed time since the last attack of your monster and trigger again when 10 seconds has past.

You have to take car of activity lyfecycle like onPause()/onResume(). It can simply be achieved with the running boolean. Also, you can use a Thread.sleep(timeBetweenGameUpdate) to avoid overflows.